# Access the dictionary elements within the dictionary itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am doing some python programming and like the dictionaries in python. I am wondering if there is a compact way to access the elements of a dictionary within the dictionary itself? For example see the following code:

```
MyDict = {'n':1, 's':2}
MyDict.update({'x' : MyDict['n']*2})
```

Often the dictionary names are long so it would be very convenient to have something like:

```
MyDict.update({'x' : self['n']*2})
```

Any idea if there is such a compact form?

Comment: No, there isn't. You could alias the dictionary beforehand if you wanted to shorten a specific line; `dct = my_dict_with_a_very_long_name_i_do_not_want_to_keep_writing`, *then* `dct.update({'x': dct['n'] * 2})`. But the argument to `update` is evaluated *before* the method gets called, it's **not** *"within the dictionary itself"*.

Answer (score 0):

Btw the easiest way is still:

```
d = {'n':1, 's':2}
d['x']=d['n']*2
```

And if wanted `self`, just rename `d` to `self`

Then don't want long names, just don't do long names

Or a way is:

```
foofoofooblahblahbarbar={'n':1, 's':2}
d=foofoofooblahblahbarbar
d['x']=d['n']*2
...
```

After all then when yo do:

```
print(foofoofooblahblahbarbar)
```

it will be the same as `d`